# Add checkbox from Contact Form 7 into mail chimp list

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp, contact-form-7, mailchimp-api-v3.0

In my WordPress site, i use "Contact Form 7" and
"Contact Form 7 MailChimp Extension" plugins for ingratiation with mailchimp.
Everything works fine!

The problem is,
that i have a checkbox for agreement getting newsletter in the contact form 7,
but I can't add a custom field in mailchimp for this checkbox.

under mailchimp list --> "List fields and *|MERGE|* tags" --> i can't find option of adding new field of checkbox type.

Under  "Signup forms" there is option to add checkbox to form in mailchimp,
but how to map this checkbox field to checkbox field in my Contact Form 7?

Thanks a lot!

```
contact form 7:

<label> fname
    [text* your-name] </label>

<label> email
    [email* your-email] </label>


<label>date
[date* date-695 date-format:DD/MM/YYYY change-month change-year  ]
</label>

[checkbox* checkbox-759   "Agree to receive a newsletter"]

[submit "Send"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mailchimp tab, go to Advanced Settings and you will see a field called "Required Acceptance Field", add checkbox-759 there.